# How to make a HTTP Post/GET request in Powershell?

Tags: post, powershell

I am using a REST API with a cloud service. Using Powershell, I need to make a HTTP Post, and also get, request.

How could I do this in a simple, concise manner?

Thanks

Comment: Is creating and using an instance of [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) simple/concise enough?

Comment: You can use System.Net.WebClient to do GET and POSTs. See: http://superuser.com/a/362156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this [HttpRest](http://poshcode.org/691) module that Jaykul wrote a try.  Use `Invoke-Http` and `Invoke-Http -verb post`.  Be sure to read the INSTALL comments because it has some prerequisites you need to install first.